# Stripped (white line in title page)

Tags: tikz-pgf, covers

[image: Titlepage]I need help to remove strip in titlepage as shown in image.
The part of titlepage who draw this is:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.69}
\raggedleft
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[yshift=2cm] at (current page.west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[fill=blue, line width=0] (0,0)
    rectangle (\paperwidth, 3cm);
    \node[anchor=east, yshift=1.6cm, xshift=\paperwidth-1in, text=white]%
      {\bfseries\fontsize{25}{0}\selectfont \hspace{-4cm} Matematikk};
  \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{110pt}

 {\Large \bf Støttebok - Matematikk \\ {\large (programmeringsdel med MATLAB)} \\}\par \par \par \par 
\vspace*{5pt}

{\large  Oppsummering med eksempler og kontrolloppgaver}\par \par 

\end{titlepage}
```

The whole code is followed here which reads titlepage1.tex page above.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,norsk,openany]{book}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{\hb@xt@3em{#1\hfil}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,decorations.softclip}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,tikzmark,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\clearpage

\input{./titlepage1.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please provide a fully compilable code.

Comment: Thanks @AndréC. I added the main.tex which reads titlepage1.tex. thanks.

Comment: Please copy the code that you have posted to a file and try to typeset it. First, it does not compile, since `\usepackage{tikz}` is missing. Second, it does not demonstrate the white line, at least not on my computer. If you have it on your computer, with this code, then we need further details about your environment. It may also be that the white line is an artefact caused by the PDF viewer, so try a few. With evince, okular, and firefox no line shows under Linux.

Comment: Never put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: You can type `\par\par\par…` any number of times and the effect is exactly the same as if you type it just once. The command `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these.